# How could I pass generic interface as a method parameter?

Tags: c#, class, generics, interface

So I'm currently experimenting with generics and I've just stumbled upon a mind shaking problem. I really have an abstract idea of how that could work, but after searching for answers I got more confused.

**I first want to create 2 new classes using generic constructors, than use their functions. One class should take in a second class as a parameter to use method Attack() and dynamically(class2.health - class1.damage), but it has to implement an IDamagable interface.**

I may do weird mistakes. Sorry.

```
public class GenericsIdeas : MonoBehaviour
{

public interface IDamagable<T>
{
    void TakeDamage(T dmg);
}

public class Enemy<T1, T2> : IDamagable<T1>
{
    T1 damage;
    T2 health;

    public void Attack(IDamagable d)
    {
        d.TakeDamage((dynamic)damage);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(T1 damage)
    {
        dynamic dmg = (dynamic)damage;
        dynamic hp = (dynamic)health;
        health -= dmg;
        Debug.Log("Enemy health: " + health);
    }

    public Enemy(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        damage = t1;
        health = t2;
    }
}

public class Player<T1, T2> : IDamagable<T1>
{
    T1 damage;
    T2 health;

    public void Attack(IDamagable d)
    {
        d.TakeDamage((dynamic)damage);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(T1 damage)
    {
        dynamic dmg = (dynamic)damage;
        dynamic hp = (dynamic)health;
         health -= dmg;
        Debug.Log("Player health: " + health);
    }

    public Player(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        damage = t1;
        health = t2;
    }
}

void Start()
{
    Player<int, int> player = new Player<int, int>(6, 10);
    Enemy<float, float> enemy = new Enemy<float, float>(4.32f, 20.61f);
    player.Attack(enemy.IDamagable); //???
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this transformation:

```
public interface IDamagable
{
    void TakeDamage<T>(T dmg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but still... how can I make this part "player.Attack(enemy.IDamagable)" happen?

Comment: I don't get how this can help me

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. I messed up reading your answer, haha. Thanks for your help! Awesome work!

Comment: Glad to help. I thought it was pretty self explanatory. Sorry to make it difficult to understand.

Comment: Yup sorry, I was just a bit tired, but I don't think I would think of that anyways!